# Multistore magento email logo not getting displayed from the correct theme folder

Tags: email, magento, graphical-logo

I have been working on a multistore setup of magento (about 20 storeviews) and it has been working quite well.
Now the sites are live I noticed my emails are not giving the correct logo for each store.
Has anybody gotten the same problem? How can I fix it?

I.e., an email from store A (with Theme-A) will get the logo from `skin/frontend/THEME-A/default/images/logo_email.gif`, while an email from store B (with Theme-B) will use `skin/frontend/base/default/images/logo_email.gif`.

So some of the stores work correctly but some don't. I have checked my folders and the logo_email is correct and present.
Magento caching is OFF at the moment.
I have been sending on multiple e-mail addresses.

The code for the the e-mail is:

```
 <td valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
```

Comment: Is it with magento standard emails that you have this problem ? Is it some email sended from frontoffice or backoffice ? You need to check which store is loaded at the moment of the email sending (go into debug).

Comment: Also, if I am not mistaken, you can use additional arguments inside the {{skin}} tag - {{skin url="..." _area='frontend' _package='yourpackage' _theme='yourtheme'}}

Comment: @Bixi They are the sales mails (new order, registration, shipment etc.) The mail displays the correct storename and language, but the logo is off.

Comment: @pspahn Yes i have found this too, but the problem there is that magento uses the same mails for all storeviews. so i cannot edit the file itself or the other stores don't show up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

when you set the email logo to images/logo_email.gif, it will use it as follows:

1. Does the logo exist in the store's theme folder? If yes, it will be used.
2. If not, it will look for the logo in the default folder
3. Finally, if the logo doesn't exist in default folder (default/default for instance), it will fallback to base/default folder.

So I recommend you to put in skin/frontend/default/default/images a logo_email.gif which will be used by default. Additionally, in case you want to use a different logo for some themes, just be sure your theme's images folder (i.e. skin/frontend/default/{MYTHEME}/images) contains an logo_email.gif.

Comment: This is exactly what does not work.
For instance lets go to my THEME-A store, with its own theme (A) and its own logo_email.gif. This one works fine and shows the logo correctly in my sales mails.
THEME-B with its own logo_email.gif (its present in the theme) links back to the base/default logo_email.gif
This happens for 4 out of the 20 stores.

All the e-mails are the same files. which is also a bit of a pain. i havent searched for an plugin yet that can replace the default mailing and adds store specific mails...

Answer (score 0):

in my case helps double " and clear cache

{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area="frontend" _package="swpackage" _theme="base"}}